# Having problems while trying to populate a todo listview using a custom adaptor?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want a user to input data through an editable text and I want to receive that data through a custom made listview, for that I am trying to use a custom adapter to add a textfield into my listview, through the `tostring()` method I have converted the data from the editable textview to a string and I am adding that string within my custom adapter to an Arraylist variable values and I’m trying to display that data through `get(0)` but either the Arraylist is not populating correctly or the data is not displaying properly because whenever I type something within my editable text and press the add button nothing happens, before this I added the string to an Array Adapter and the listview was populating normally, what am I doing wrong?

```
public class todoFragment extends ListFragment {

private EditText mToDoField;
private Button mAdd;
UsersAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.todo_title);
}

public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public Context context;
    public ArrayList<String> values;

    public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, 0, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);

        TextView todoTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_TextView);

        todoTextView.setText(values.get(0));

        return convertView;
    }
}

@TargetApi(9) // remember this for isEmpty()
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);

    ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), todoList);
    ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) v.findViewById (android.R.id.list);
    listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mToDoField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.todo_editText);

    mAdd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            String toDo = mToDoField.getText().toString().trim();

            if (toDo.isEmpty()){
                return;
            }

            mAdapter.values.add(toDo);

            mToDoField.setText("");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: just try mAdapter.add(toDo); instead of mAdapter.values.add(toDo); otherwise you need to call NotifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should not be doing

```
todoTextView.setText(values.get(0));
```

Because this will always return the first element of the `values` list. You should do

```
todoTextView.setText(values.get(position));
```

Secondly,

```
mAdapter.values.add(toDo);
```

is not really right. It will work, but its not the best practise. Try using something like

```
mAdapter.add(toDo);
```

or

```
values.add(toDo);
```

Now once you've added the data to the list, you need to notify the adapter that the data set has been changed. This is done by

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If you use the direct method for modifying the data set, i.e. `mAdapter.add(toDo)`, you don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: @Simas Oh thanks for the info, didn't know that. But we would need that if we use `values.add(toDo);`

Answer (score 1):

When you manually update the data don't forget to call:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `mAdapter.values.add(toDo);` Use`mAdapter.add(toDo);` 
 
Look at the Add Method Of `ArrayAdpter` Class, it Itself use `notifyDataSetChanged()` so need to write any extra line of code:

```
public void add(T object) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mOriginalValues != null) {
            mOriginalValues.add(object);
        } else {
            mObjects.add(object);
        }
    }
    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```